# c with eclipse, make: *** Error 1

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile

i´m making a proyect with eclipse in c languaje and i met with this error that i don´t know how to solve. I would thank any help.

11:04:11 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project POrueba- ****
make all
Building target: POrueba-
Invoking: GCC C Linker
gcc -L"/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug" -o "POrueba-"  ./src/POrueba-.o   -lLibreria-nivel
/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug/libLibreria-nivel.so: referencia a `waddch' sin definir

/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug/libLibreria-nivel.so: referencia a`wborder' sin definir
/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug/libLibreria-nivel.so: referencia a `init_pair' sin definir

/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug/libLibreria-nivel.so: referencia a`wbkgd' sin definir
/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug/libLibreria-nivel.so: referencia a `wrefresh' sin definir

/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug/libLibreria-nivel.so: referencia a`keypad' sin definir
/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug/libLibreria-nivel.so: referencia a `initscr' sin definir

/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug/libLibreria-nivel.so: referencia a`start_color' sin definir
/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug/libLibreria-nivel.so: referencia a `newwin' sin definir

/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug/libLibreria-nivel.so: referencia a`delwin' sin definir
/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug/libLibreria-nivel.so: referencia a `printw' sin definir

/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug/libLibreria-nivel.so: referencia a`stdscr' sin definir
/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug/libLibreria-nivel.so: referencia a `endwin' sin definir

/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug/libLibreria-nivel.so: referencia a`noecho' sin definir
/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug/libLibreria-nivel.so: referencia a `wmove' sin definir

/home/utnso/workspace/Libreria-nivel/Debug/libLibreria-nivel.so: referencia a`werase' sin definir
collect2: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1

make: *** [POrueba-] Error 1

11:04:12 Build Finished (took 642ms)

Comment: You are going to need to provide some code in order for us to help. Also please read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Could you convert the error messages to english? Looks like you failed to link a needed shared object library.

Comment: Please describe what your program is trying to accomplish. Also as mike mentioned, you will get more replies on this site if you convert your error message into English.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dependency issue.  One of your shared objects (libLibreria-nivel.so) seems to reference another library that has the function/variable/definition of init_pair.  You need to find out where these definitions are, and link them appropriately.